# How to fetch data from recordset to html div

Tags: html, css, sql, node.js, express

I am trying to make a Inventory Manager to keep track of various fishing equipment. I currently am able to input data to a SQL server database using html forms. I am trying to load data from a select statement into a div on my index.html page. I am using node js and express to allow the html to talk to SQL server.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fishing Inventory</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="AddPerson.html">Add New Person</a>
        <a href="AddHook.html">Add New Hook</a>
        <a href="AddSoftPlastic.html">Add New Soft Plastic</a>
        <a href="AddRod.html">Add New Rod</a>
        <a href="AddReel.html">Add New Reel</a>
        <a href="AddLine.html">Add New Line</a>
        <a id="SeeHooks">See Hooks</a>
        <a id="SeeSP">See Soft Plastics</a>
        <a id="SeeRods">See Rods</a>
        <a id="SeeReels">See Reels</a>
        <a id="SeeLine">See Line</a>
    </div>

    <div class="mainHeader">
        <h1>Fishing Inventory Manager</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="DBcontainer">
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            

/* On button click, I want the recordSet to be displayed in this div */

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>

        </form>

        

    </div>

</body>

</html>

<style>
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }

    /* The navigation bar */
    .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
        top: 0;
        /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
        width: 100%;
        /* Full width */
    }

    /* Links inside the navbar */
    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Change background on mouse-over */
    .navbar a:hover {
        background: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }

    /* Main content */
    .main {
        margin-top: 30px;
        /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
    }

    .mainHeader {
        position: relative;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .DBcontainer {
        background-color: white;
        margin: auto;
        width: 80%;
        line-height: 100%;
        margin-top: 30px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .button {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .center {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sql = require('mssql');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname)); //__dir and not _dir
var port = 8000; // you can use any port
app.listen(port);
console.log('server on ' + port);

var config = {
    server: "localhost",
    database: "FishingInventory",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    port: 1433
};


app.post('/hook', function (req, res) {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
    var requ = new sql.Request(conn);
    var hookCompany = req.body.Hook_Company;
    var hookSize = req.body.Hook_Size;
    var hookType = req.body.Hook_Type;

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        var sql = "INSERT INTO hooks (company, size, hook_type) VALUES ('" + hookCompany + "', '" + hookSize + "', '" + hookType + "')";

        requ.query(sql, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send('Records were updated');
            }
        });

        conn.close();
    });

});

app.post('/SP', function (req, res) {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
    var requ = new sql.Request(conn);
    var SPCompany = req.body.SP_Company;
    var SPSize = req.body.SP_Color;
    var SPType = req.body.SP_Type;

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        var sql = "INSERT INTO soft_plastics (company, size, sp_type) VALUES ('" + SPCompany + "', '" + SPSize + "', '" + SPType + "')";

        requ.query(sql, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send('Records were updated');
            }
        });

        conn.close();
    });
});

app.post('/reel', function (req, res) {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
    var requ = new sql.Request(conn);
    var reelCompany = req.body.Reel_Company;
    var reelSize = req.body.Reel_Size;

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        var sql = "INSERT INTO reels (company, size) VALUES ('" + reelCompany + "', '" + reelSize + "')";

        requ.query(sql, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send('Records were updated');
            }
        });

        conn.close();
    });
});

app.post('/line', function (req, res) {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
    var requ = new sql.Request(conn);
    var lineCompany = req.body.Line_Company;
    var lineSize = req.body.Line_ibTest;

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        var sql = "INSERT INTO line (company, ib_test) VALUES ('" + lineCompany + "', '" + lineSize + "')";

        requ.query(sql, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send('Records were updated');
            }
        });

        conn.close();
    });
});

app.post('/rod', function (req, res) {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
    var requ = new sql.Request(conn);
    var RodCompany = req.body.Rod_Company;
    var RodFeet = req.body.Rod_Feet;
    var RodInches = req.body.Rod_Inches;
    var reelID =  req.body.Reel_ID;
    var lineID = req.body.Line_ID;

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        var sql = "INSERT INTO rods (company, feet, inches, reel_id, line_id)" + 
        "VALUES ('" + RodCompany + "', '" + RodFeet + "', '"+ RodInches +"', '"+ reelID +"', '"+ lineID +"')";

        requ.query(sql, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send('Records were updated');
            }
        });

        conn.close();
    });
});

app.post('/person', function (req, res) {
    var FirstName = req.body.Fname;
    var LastName = req.body.Lname;
    var HooksID = req.body.Hooks_ID;
    var SoftPlasticsID =  req.body.Soft_Plastics_ID;
    var RodID = req.body.Rods_ID;
    var numOfHooks = req.body.Num_Of_hooks;
    var numOfSoftPlastics = req.body.Num_OF_Soft_Plastics;

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        var sql = "INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, hooks_id, sp_id, rods_id, num_hooks, num_sp)" + 
        "VALUES ('" + FirstName + "', '" + LastName + "', '"+ HooksID +"', '"+ SoftPlasticsID +"', '"+ RodID +"', '"+ numOfHooks +"', '"+ numOfSoftPlastics +"')";

        requ.query(sql, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send('Records were updated');
            }
        });

        conn.close();
    });
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
    var requ = new sql.Request(conn);
    
    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM person";

        requ.query(sql, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send(recordset);
            }
        });

        conn.close();
    });
});
```

I changed the server name, user and pass for security purposes. They are the proper values on my project

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that strikes me is that you should change your 'select' route method from post to get...

eg:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
```

becomes

```
app.get('/person', function (req, res) {
```

then add a script to your page that basically calls the person route and populates a container on your page with the results.

```
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var person = xhttp.responseText;
    var element = document.getElementById("PersonContainer");
    person.forEach(function(item, index) {
      element.innerHTML += '<li><p>' + item.name + '</p></li>'
    });
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "/person", true);
xhttp.send();
</script>
```

finally make sure the 'PersonContainer' element exists on your page...

```
<div id='PersonContainer'></div>
```

note that the above code has been simplified and can be done much better, this is just to help point you in the right direction...

Comment: I can put the script section inside the form and div of PersonContainer?

Comment: No, the script section should be placed before the closing body tag. The script will still be available throughout the page. N.B the script is a basic script to get you on your way to debugging and understanding what's going on. it can and should be improved...

Comment: I have the script in the proper place, I followed a w3schools tutorial on xmlhttprequests. I wrapped the entire script in a function and on the button click I have the function in the "onclick" portion but when I click it nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding the line console.log(‘click working’) to the top of the function just to make sure the click event handle is working. If you press F12 on your keyboard to open the developer tools you should see the output. If you don’t then you need to double check what you doing with the onclick part. If there are any errors please update your question... or you could try moving the script into the ‘head’ section of the page

Comment: The console.log above the var http isnt showing, seems like my onclick isnt working.

Comment: Well at least you have found the fault, I suggest you log a new question, as this is going out of scope... or have a look at w3c js click events, should provide sufficient info to help you